# Rename files in directory using a script

Tags: bash

Our SVN users are uploading files with a certain tag name like,

`filename_INT
filename2_INT
filename3_INT`

I need my script to rename these files by removing the _INT to its original filename like

`filename
filename2
filename3`

What is the best method to do this in bash?

I tried using sed but it fails on the script but not on the command line,

`[root@hostname tags]# echo filename_INT | sed 's/_INT[a-z.]*//g'`

filename.php

Comment: Do you want to rename these files in SVN too, or just locally?

Answer (score 6):

This one-liner should take care of all the `*_INT` files in the current directory:

```
for file in *_INT; do mv "$file" "${file%_INT}"; done
```

If you want to do it recursively for all files and subdirectories, you can do like this:

```
find path -name '*_INT' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)_INT$/mv "&" "\1"/'
```

The output of this is a bunch of `mv` commands printed but NOT executed. If it looks good and you want to execute it, just pipe it to `sh` like this:

```
find path -name '*_INT' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)_INT$/mv "&" "\1"/' | sh
```

Comment: I think it is a typo here, $file instead of $i

Answer (score 1):

Does this need to be done in your Subversion repository, or just locally?

If just locally, you can use `find` to find all of your files:

```
find . -name "*_INT"
```

Do the files have white spaces in their names? If not, the following should work:

```
find . -name "*_INT" | while read file
do
    mv $file ${file%_INT}
done
```

The `${file%_INT}` uses a bash/kornshell mechanism called [Pattern Matching Operators](http://oreilly.com/catalog/korn2/chapter/ch04.html#ksh2-ch-4-sect-5.3). These can quickly filter off prefixes and suffixes from file names. For example, if:

```
$ file=foo.txt_INT
$ echo $file         #Prints "foo.txt_INT"
$ echo ${file%_INT}  #Prints "foo.txt"
$ echo ${file#foo}   #Prints ".txt_INT"
```

Now that you have the file's old name and new name, you can simply use the `mv` command. Of course, there could be a file already existing with that name. Is that okay for that to get overwritten. If not, you'll have to figure out how to handle it:

```
find . -name "*_INT" | while read file
do
    if [ ! -e $file ]
    then
        mv $file ${file%_INT}
    else
        echo "File ${file%_INT} already exists"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command:

```
rename 's/_INT//' *_INT
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I struggled a bit with janos script but eventually sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `rename` command should be your best bet.  My man page tells me (I verified) that this works:

```
rename _INT "" *_INT
```